# XSL get content by key from another xml child

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my example xml example :

```
<bloc id = "mybloc">
 <ref_ex ref = "data1"/>
 <ref_ex ref = "data2"/>
</bloc>

<ex id = "data1">
    <name>Hello</name>
    .. (something else)
</ex>
<ex id = "data2">
    <name>Hello Me !</name>
    .. (something else)
</ex>
```

I would like to get this html code like :

```
<a href="#data1">Hello</a>
<a href="#data2">Hello Me!</a>
```

I've tried with this xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">
  <xsl:output method = "html"/>
    <xsl:template match = "ref_ex">
        <a href = "#{@ref}">
            <xsl:template match = "ex" use="@ref">
                <xsl:value-of select = "@name"/>
            </xsl:template>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I get this error :

```
element template only allowed as child of stylesheet !
```

someone have any idea to do that ? by respecting my format.

Comment: Is that your full stylesheet?

Comment: You have to place `<xsl:template>` inside a `<xsl:stylesheet>` (or `<xsl:transform>`. Also, your XML is not well formed. Post your full XSL and include the root of your XML in the example.

Comment: no just a part of what i can't done.

Comment: The error is saying that the `<xsl:template>` element is misplaced. Post your full stylesheet (or at least show the code around `<xsl:template>`)

Comment: the xsl:template is inside an xsl:stylesheet, everything is ok, i just want to get an element from another xml block (i can't publish the full stylesheet) but i'll edit the post to add some info

Comment: I would not say that "everything is ok". You simply cannot use `xsl:template` inside `xsl:template`.

Comment: The error clearly says that there is a `template` element that is misplaced (not directly below `stylesheet`).

Comment: @MathiasMüller has the answer to your error.

Comment: everything is ok without the xsl:template inside the other.. so i can't do it like this ?

Comment: I think I know what you want to do. You want to define a key. You have to do that with `<xsl:key>` and outside the `<xsl:template>` and then use `key(...)` to reference them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments section: You simply cannot use `xsl:template` inside another `xsl:template`. Why? Because it makes awful little sense. I suggest you read about the basics of XSLT in order to understand the concept of tempate matches.

The stylesheet below transforms `ex` elements into `a` elements if their ID is referenced in a `bloc` element. Another viable solution, as suggested by @helderarocha, would be to use keys.

Assuming correct input (a root element to make it well-formed):

```
<root>
<bloc id = "mybloc">
 <ref_ex ref = "data1"/>
 <ref_ex ref = "data2"/>
</bloc>

<ex id = "data1">
    <name>Hello</name>
    <!--.. (something else)-->
</ex>
<ex id = "data2">
    <name>Hello Me !</name>
     <!--.. (something else)-->
</ex>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bloc[@id='mybloc']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ex[id = current()/ref_ex/@ref]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ex">
    <a href="{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a href="data1">Hello</a>
   <a href="data2">Hello Me !</a>
</root>
```